# Not able to connect to Postgres database from golang Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose

I am trying to connect to a Postgres database in a separate container from another separate container that stores a Go server:

```
Pool, err = pgxpool.Connect(context.Background(),"postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres")
```

After doing so, I receive the following error:

```
2020/09/25 13:40:08 failed to connect to `host=postgres user=postgres database=postgres`: hostname resolving error (lookup postgres on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host)
```

Here is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always
  server:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "2302:2302"
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
```

I am successfully able to connect to the Postgres database from my OS. Here are the Postgres container initialization logs:

```
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  | 2020-09-25 15:37:50.529 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 9.3.0) 9.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_1  | 2020-09-25 15:37:50.529 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2020-09-25 15:37:50.529 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2020-09-25 15:37:50.532 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2020-09-25 15:37:50.536 UTC [20] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-09-25 15:37:49 UTC
postgres_1  | 2020-09-25 15:37:50.540 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Any clues would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to share a network

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:alpine
        environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        ports:
        - 5432:5432
        restart: always
        networks: [ "go_develop" ]

    server:
        build: .
        depends_on:
        - postgres
        ports:
        - "2302:2302"
        - "80:80"
        restart: always
        networks: [ "go_develop" ]

networks:
    go_develop:
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work as I get the same error.

Comment: Also, it is very strange that Postgres is accessed on port ```53``` instead of ```5432```.

Comment: 53 is DNS, it looks like it trying to resolve Postgres host, try to debug your connect string.