# Using Golang with Gin, pgxpool and issue when connecting from docker container

Tags: cockroachdb

I have a written a simple golang CRUD example connecting to `cockroachdb` using `pgxpool/pgx`.
All the CRUD operations are exposed as REST api using Gin framework.
By using curl command or Postman, the operations (GET/POST/DELETE) are working good and the data reflect in the database.
Next I dockerized this simple app and trying to run. The application seems to get struck in the below code

```
func Connection(conn_string string) gin.HandlerFunc {
  log.Println("Connection: 0", conn_string)
  config, err := pgxpool.ParseConfig(conn_string)
  log.Println("Connection: 1", config.ConnString())
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }
  log.Println("Connection: 2")
  pool, err := pgxpool.ConnectConfig(context.Background(), config) // gets struck here
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }
  log.Println("Connection: 3")
  return func(c *gin.Context) {
      c.Set("pool", pool)
      c.Next()
  }
}
```

The code seems to get frozen after printing `Connection: 2` at the line
`pool, err := pgxpool.ConnectConfig(context.Background(), config)`

After few minutes, I am getting a error
`FATA[0120] failed to connect to` host=192.165.xx.xxx user=user_name database=dbname`: dial error (timeout: dial tcp 192.165.xx.xxx:5432: i/o timeout).

Below is my docker file

```
FROM golang as builder
WORKDIR /catalog
COPY main.go ./
COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go get .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o catalog .

# deployment image
FROM scratch
#FROM alpine:3.17.1
# copy ca-certificates from builder
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
WORKDIR /bin/
COPY --from=builder /catalog .
CMD [ "./catalog" ]
#CMD go run /catalog/main.go
EXPOSE 8080
```

Note, I tried getting into the container `bash` shell and could `ping` the target ip `192.165.xx.xxx`.

Please let me know why the pgxpool fails to connect to DB in the docker container but work in host (ubuntu) without any issue.

Comment: There is one such related incident https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64065419/not-able-to-connect-to-postgres-database-from-golang-docker-container and the difference is that for me the CRDB is already existing and unable to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update-2** : The real issue is passing the arguments while starting the application. When the arguments are passed correctly, this is started working.

**Update-1: I still see issues while running the query and could produce it outside the docker as well.**

I could fix it with upgraded pgxpool v5 instead of v4.
All I did is
`go get -u github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgxpool`, used it in the code as well
and it worked as expected.
This could be a known bug but could not find any related issue to include it in this post.
Below is the final code that is working

```
func Connection(conn_string string) gin.HandlerFunc {
    log.Println("Connection: 0", conn_string)
    config, err := pgxpool.ParseConfig(conn_string)
    log.Println("Connection: 1", config.ConnString())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("Connection: 2")
    //pool, err := pgxpool.ConnectConfig(context.Background(), config)
    pool, err := pgxpool.NewWithConfig(context.Background(), config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("Connection: 3")
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Set("pool", pool)
        c.Next()
    }
}
```